# How to pull commit when already up to date

Tags: git

I did following commands locally:

```
git checkout commit
git add -A
git commit -m 'commit'
```

And now I want to pull changes on my server but I get "Already up-to-date" error.

Why there is nothing to pull but I know that on local there are files that are not on the server?

Comment: Do you want to "push" your changes to the server?

Comment: Can you click [edit] and include a bit more detail of what command you're trying to run which gives the "Already up to date" message, and where you're running it? The output of "git status" run in the same place would also be useful.

Comment: Pulling is used to get revisions on the upstream branch (probably on a remote, though not necessarily so) that are missing from the local branch, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

From the sound of it, you did a git checkout of an older commit. Try

```
git checkout master
git pull
git push
```

Comment: If they have changes on a different branch, then this will do absolutely nothing.